# jQuery clone radio form element issue when clicking

Tags: jquery

So I am trying to clone a radio form element from one place to another for display purposes but would need the settings in the original location to be updated as well.  So I use jQuery clone and bind a on change event to the clone elements so that when the cloned version value changes, it updates the original location.  However I seem to have a problem with the radio buttons sometimes not clicking.  In addition I am not sure if the original radio values have changed as looking at the dom does not tell me anything.

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/KNnmp/

JS:

```
    $( '.edit' ).click( function() {
    var values = $( '.original-location .values' ),
        clonedValues = values.clone( true, true );

    $( '.value', clonedValues ).each( function ( index ) {
        $( this ).on( 'change', function() {
            values.find( '.value' ).eq( index ).click();
        } );
    } );

    // append to location and show settings
    $( '.edit-location .settings' ).append( clonedValues ).hide().slideDown( 'fast' );
} );
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="original-location">
    <div class="values">
        <label>On <input type="radio" name="choose" value="on" class="value" /></label><label>Off <input type="radio" name="choose" value="off" /></label>
    </div><!--.values-->
</div><!--.original-location-->

<div class="edit-location">
    <div class="settings"></div><!--.settings-->
</div><!--.edit-location-->

<a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
```

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code you are looking for, you had following issues in your code

1. way of setting the value was wrong
2. way of using `change` was wrong
3. and you have to change the group name when you adding new group

once you fixed those your code will looks like following.

```
$('.edit').click(function () {
    var values = $('.original-location .values'); 
    var clonedValues = values.clone(true, true);

    // changing the name of the cloned radio buttons. so those will become a new group.
    clonedValues.find('input[type=radio]').each(function (index) {
        var name = $(this).prop('name');
        // appending length to the name, so it will become unique name for this group
        $(this).prop('name', name + $('.values').length);
    });

    // append to location and show settings
    $('.edit-location .settings').append(clonedValues).hide().slideDown('fast');
});

// apling change event globally
$('.original-location .values').on('change', 'input[type=radio]', function () {
    // set the original values based on cloned selection
    $("input[name='choose'][value=" + $(this).val() + "]").prop('checked', true);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KNnmp/1/

Comment: Hi, thanks for input however this will not work for me because my input names are dynamic.  Also there will be multiple radio buttons that have value on/off for many different radio inputs.  Only name is different.  So my input name looks something very complicated like this name="choose[][item][][selection][][value][id]"...as example...

Comment: in above code, you only need to know the name of `original location` radio group. others are automaticaly set by the above code

Comment: May I ask if you know why my code renders the radio button in weird way?

Comment: In your code this :     clonedValues.find('input[type=radio]').each(function (index) {
        var name = $(this).prop('name');
        $(this).prop('name', name + $('.values').length);
    });

Comment: What does that do?  Because I can comment it out and it would still work.

Comment: it is changing the name of the cloned group. without it your code wont work see the sample link.

Comment: sorry I am just trying to understand the code...I don't like copying and pasting code that I don't understand...in your sample the cloned values are not appended to the settings div...so I am abit confused..

Comment: @Rick : `$('.edit-location .settings').append(clonedValues).hide().slideDown('fast');` here it is

Comment: @Rick, added comments on the code and now you can understand the code